# Two identical operations produce differently structured output

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am having difficulty with some code I have written. Previously the code was working properly, but now it is not.

To highlight the problem I supply two dataframes.

I have two data frames, dat and cleansvm. When I subset both frames in the same way I get the following:

```
head(dat[-train,])        
        x.1        x.2 y
2  2.183643  3.6888733 1
3  1.164371  3.5865884 1
4  3.595281  1.6690922 1
5  2.329508 -0.2852355 1
6  1.179532  4.4976616 1
10 1.694612  2.5101084 1

head(dat[-train,"y"])
1 1 1 1 1 1

class(dat)
[1] "data.frame" 

head(cleansvm[-train,])   
   Interpretation    col1     col2
1:              R       0        0      
2:              R       0        0     
3:              R       0        0       
4:              R       0        0      
5:              R       0        0       
6:              R       0        0

head(cleansvm[-train,"Interpretation"])
   Interpretation
1:              R
2:              R
3:              R
4:              R
5:              R
6:              R

class(cleansvm)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

My questions are as follows: why is the form of `head(dat[-train,"y"])` and `head(cleansvm[-train,"Interpretation"])` different and can I do anything to get `head(cleansvm[-train,"Interpretation"])`in the same form as`head(dat[-train,"y"])`?

`head(dat[-train,"y"])` can be used later in my code to form a table, whereas `head(cleansvm[-train,"Interpretation"])` due to its length cannot.

I'm pretty sure the class of cleansvm is whats causing the problem but I don't know why. I tried converting it to a straight forward data frame (it's currently a data table) but that didn't help. I also tried using t() on `head(cleansvm[-train,"Interpretation"])` but that caused errors later on.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Dataframe subsetting can drop the `dim` attribute. Try `dat[-train,"y", drop = FALSE]`. And `cleansvm` is not just a `"data.frame"`.

Answer (score 0):

`cleansvm` is a `data.table` object. To get the expected output you need to either do

```
head(cleansvm[-train, Interpretation])
```

or

```
head(cleansvm[-train,"Interpretation", with = F])
```